# How to use selenium experimental options in selenium driver arguments?

Tags: python, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

```
from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['--incognito',prefs]
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
```

**https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40191872/91153176-80b92680-e6dd-11ea-8b5d-b1e9d77cd049.png**
here is my code and i want to add prefs for disable image during website loading...but i am not able to understand how can i?please help me about this

Comment: Can you add profile.***profile.default_content_settings":2*** inside your prefs list also could you specify your problem with your website.

Comment: ya i did but its working fine with simple code that is ''' chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs) ''' .but i don't understand how  to add in this coz its only take string..also i found this link https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/      for all command but neither image options show here